# Filtering entries by multiple categories with multiple filters

Tags: entries, categories, filter, forloop

I'm trying to build a category filter on a page that lists houses that are for sale. The idea of the filter is to make it possible to select houses which, for example, are for sale or rent, have a certain amount of rooms, a minimum/maximum price and eventually a search option to search at location, postal code or street address.

I first built one filter, which filters if a house is for sale or for rent. This filter works with two anchor buttons in a list. I now want to add the next filter, which is the amount of rooms. This filter should be a dropdown (a select tag with options in it).

I got both filters to work, but I want them to stack upon each other. So when the houses that are for sale are being shown and the user clicks on houses with 4+ rooms, it shows the houses that are for sale AND have 4+ rooms.

What I came up with so far

The filter for sale/rent houses

```
<ul class="button-group round">
 {% for offerCategory in craft.categories.group('offerTypes').find() %}
  <li>
   <a class="mart-button" href="{{craft.request.url}}/?category={{ offerCategory.slug }}">{{ offerCategory.title }}</a>
  </li>
 {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

The filter for the amount of rooms

```
<select onChange="window.location.href=this.value">
 {% for offerRooms in craft.categories.group('offerRoomTypes').find() %}
  <option value="{{craft.request.url}}/?category={{ offerRooms.slug }}" name>{{ offerRooms.title }}</option>
 {% endfor %}
</select>
```

And the rest

```
{% if craft.request.getParam('category') is not null %}

 {% set offerCategory = craft.categories.slug(craft.request.getParam('category')) %}
 {% set offerRooms = craft.categories.slug(craft.request.getParam('category')) %}

 {% set offers = craft.entries({
    section: 'offers',
    relatedTo: [
        'and',
        { targetElement: offerCategory },
        { targetElement: offerRooms }
    ]
 }) %}

{% else %}

 {% set offers = craft.entries.section('offers').find() %}

{% endif %}
```

The URL that's being fetched is now: .../?category=forsale and when selecting rooms .../?category=4rooms. What I want to achieve is something like .../?category=forsale,4rooms (I'm nog sure if that's the right way). 
If someone also can tell me directly how the search should be implemented that's welcome as well ;). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing the category as a comma delineated string and using `craft.request.getParam('category')` the second time will not grab the second variable `4rooms`.  First you need to parse that string into an array. This will create an array `['forsale','4rooms']`. Use the parts of that array to assign to your other variables.

```
{% set params = craft.request.getParam('category')|split(',') %}
{% set offerCategory = craft.categories.slug(params[0]) %}
{% set offerRooms = craft.categories.slug(params[1]) %}
```

Comment: Hey aran, thanks for taking time for this. At the time I decided to filter them with jQuery instead, since I won't be getting a lot of entries. I will mark your answer as correct because I think it would as you say.